# How to open a ContentPage from a ContentView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, contentview

I have a `Xamarin.forms.Maps` in a `ContentView` and I am using that view in a `ListView`. I need to open a new page when clicking the map.

I tried like below:

```
MapClicked="MapClicked"

private async void MapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (History)((Map)sender).BindingContext;
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Pages.Page1());
}
```

When I tap the map these lines are triggering, but Page1 is not opening. So what is the exact way to open a `ContentPage` from a `ContentView`?

Reference: [Xamarin Forms: How to bind the position value of Xamarin.forms.Maps inside the ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390620/xamarin-forms-how-to-bind-the-position-value-of-xamarin-forms-maps-inside-the-l)

Comment: Hi, I created a baisc demo to test the mapView in a `ListView`. The navigation works fine when clicking the map. How did you define the listView? Please post the related code about the xaml, it'll help to reproduce the issue to get the cause.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT For the map, I am using a contentview. Navigation is to implemented on the contentview. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390620/how-to-bind-the-position-value-of-xamarin-forms-maps-inside-the-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `NavigationPage` as root page to navigate. read more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical